# static class'member across threads after redeploy web app (java web-app, jboss4)

Tags: java, multithreading, static, jboss, share

In a web app a class is defined so:

```
public class ThreadSession {
private static final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 1;
static private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);
```

then there's one or more threads created by:

```
class wsClientThread extends Thread {
public void run() { ... }
```

...

```
wsClientThread clientThread = new wsClientThread(clientSocket);
clientThread.start();
```

let's call these thread A, B, ..

Inside these threads accessing to ThreadSession.semaphore work fine as expected,
but after redeployed the web-app (by jboss 4.05), and reload my index.jsp, inside thread A, B,.. ThreadSession.semaphore is null (but ThreadSession.MAX_AVAILABLE = 1)

Cannot understand why this .. can anyone help me ?

Thx
Cristian

Comment: Where are you getting null? ThreadSession is private. How do other threads access it?

Comment: inside thread A, B ... but only after re-deployed app
If restart jboss the web-app work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests the problem was disappears
I think it was caused by some instability in the application server (jboss 4)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).